# form post submit button counter to store data in .txt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have spent a couple hours reading up on different methods on how to go about storing data for a submit button counter in a text file.

```
<form action="/enquiry.php" method="post" name="form">
<label>Name *</label>
<input id="Name" maxlength="100" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
<label>Email Address *</label>
<input id="Email" maxlength="100" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
<button class="btn btn-default" id="submit" name="submit" type="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to simply have a 'count.txt' file in the main server directory, for which that is displayed on the contact page (Button clicked: X times), every time some one clicks 'Submit' on the contact form.

Can any one recommend the best & safest way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/18237034/4178487

Comment: @JasonK That is for a page counter... I want to keep count of how many users click on the Submit button :)

Comment: Then only have it run when the user clicks submit.

Comment: @JasonK my PHP is very limited, hence why I am seeking a bit of help... I am not even sure if this is the safest way to do this type of thing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index.php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$file = "count.txt";
$count = file_get_contents($file);
$plus1 = $count + 1;

file_put_contents($file, $plus1);

echo "Button clicked ".":".$plus1." times";


    }
?>

<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<label>Name *</label>
<input id="Name" maxlength="100" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
<label>Email Address *</label>
<input id="Email" maxlength="100" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
<button class="btn btn-default" id="submit" name="submit" type="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is simple example in which i write all my code is `index.php` and my `count.txt` file is in same folder where `index.php`. Please note if you use `action= "/enquiry.php"` then use my `php` `coding` in `enquiry.php`. Also please change `file path` according to your file path.

Comment: Thanks for this... but the enquiry.php file is directed to a /thank-you.htm after the form has run. How would I echo the code on the /thank-you.htm page? Thanks :)

Comment: Never mind... had a play about and sussed it. Thank you very much :)